# CSS drop down menu weird behavior

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a pure CSS menu but am not sure what I'm doing wrong. The  problem is that when I hover on the parent element, the child list opens "within" it, which kind of opens another box and pushes all other parents down. I know words don't do the scenario justice, so I'd be grateful if someone could try this out and tell me what's wrong:

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Employees</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Add new</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit details</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Attendance</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">View report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Upload attendance</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Broadcast</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">To all</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">To Managers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Begin styling navigation */

.navigation {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.navigation li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navigation ul {
    display: none;
}

.navigation > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigation li:hover {
        background-color: #aaa;
}

.navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* End styling navigation */
```

Comment: I know words can't describe it, but a http://jsfiddle.net could.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks! Didn't know something like that existed. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position: absolute` to the CSS of `.navigation li:hover > ul` like this:

```
.navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

---

```css
.navigation {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.navigation li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ff6600;
    padding: 5px;
}

.navigation ul {
    display: none;
}

.navigation > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigation li:hover {
        background-color: #aaa;
}

.navigation li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Employees</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Add new</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit details</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Attendance</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">View report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Upload attendance</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Broadcast</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">To all</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">To Managers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can't believe how close I was for all the frustration I was going through! :) Will accept this as answer as soon as the site allows me.